# Drawing an ellipse around an edge in forest

Tags: linguistics, forest

I have the following code for a slide. I would like to draw a red ellipse around the arrow. I want to be it present on one overlay only to put the focus there during explanation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}



\begin{document}

\frame{


\begin{forest}
[S
  [NP$_x$ [he,tier=words]]
  [VP x z y
    [V, [V x y,edge={<-},tier=words [baked]]]
    [NP$_z$ [her,tier=words]]
    [NP$_y$ [a cake,roof,tier=words]]]]
\end{forest}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It sounds more like you mean *ellipse*.  If you really mean *ellipsis*, you might want to explain how that relates to *around*

Comment: Ups, it is the same word in German.

Comment: Use `fit` with the `tikz` key or add the code directly. What's the problem exactly? What have you tried?

Comment: I found an explanation that helps me fit an ellipse around some nodes, but I do not want to include the nodes, just the arrow.

Comment: Ref to @StefanMüller. Replace `V,` with `V,tikz={\node[inner sep=1pt,draw=blue,fit=()(!1),ellipse] {};}`. But the ellipse is containing node V `()`an its first child `(!1)`.

Comment: Please ask one question per question. The overlay question is addressed elsewhere, so I suggest focusing on the ellipse issue here. If you can't solve the other part with the existing solutions, post a new question about that. (There is 'standard' Forest-specific code for doing this, adapted from the 'standard' Ti*k*Z code used for the same purpose.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coordinates are just nodes with zero size, basically. At any rate, `fit` works as well with coordinates as nodes, so you can just use the relevant parent and child anchors.

[image: ellipsed arrow]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [S
    [NP$_x$
      [he,tier=words]
    ]
    [VP x z y
      [V,
        [V x y,edge={<-}, tier=words, tikz+={
          \node [fit=(.child anchor) (!u.parent anchor), draw, ellipse, inner ysep=1.5pt] {};
        }
          [baked]
        ]
      ]
      [NP$_z$
        [her,tier=words]
      ]
      [NP$_y$
        [a cake,roof,tier=words]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

If you need this often, you can, of course, create a style. I would also straighten out the edge on the right, which looks unhappy to me.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}
\forestset{%
  circle edge/.style={
    tikz+={
          \node [fit=(.child anchor) (!u.parent anchor), draw, ellipse, inner ysep=1.5pt] {};
        }
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [S
    [NP$_x$
      [he,tier=words]
    ]
    [VP x z y
      [V,
        [V x y,edge={<-}, tier=words, circle edge
          [baked]
        ]
      ]
      [NP$_z$, calign with current
        [her,tier=words]
      ]
      [NP$_y$
        [a cake,roof,tier=words]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: <code>circle edge</code> with straightened edge]

Answer (score 2):

You can add`,tikz={\node[inner sep=1pt,draw=blue,anchor=center,yshift=-2.93cm,xshift=-0.05cm,ellipse, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.8cm] {};}` after the node `V`. Bad: explict shift to arrow necessary.

The size can be defined by `minimum width=<length>` and `minimum height=<length>`.

For line width you can use also `thick`, `ultra thick`,...

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{linguistics}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{linguistics}
\begin{document}

\frame{


\begin{forest}
[S
  [NP$_x$ [he,tier=words]]
  [VP x z y
    [V,tikz={\node[inner sep=1pt,draw=blue,anchor=center,yshift=-2.93cm,xshift=-0.05cm,ellipse, minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height=0.8cm] {};} [V x y,edge={<-},tier=words [baked]]]
    [NP$_z$ [her,tier=words]]
    [NP$_y$ [a cake,roof,tier=words]]]]
\end{forest}

}

\end{document}
```