# overlays of edge related shapes in forest

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, forest

My question [Drawing an ellipse around an edge in forest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355365/drawing-an-ellipse-around-an-edge-in-forest/#18561) resulted in the following code with a `forest` style `circle edge`. I want to show and hide this edge for presentations with `beamer`but cannot figure out how to do this. I already found `visible on` but I cannot combine this with the forest style.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}

\forestset{%
  circle edge/.style={
    tikz+={
          \node [fit=(.child anchor) (!u.parent anchor), draw=red, ellipse, inner ysep=1.5pt, line
            width=0.25mm] {};
        }
  },
}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}
\forestset{
  visible on/.style={
    for ancestors'={
      /tikz/visible on={#1},
      edge={/tikz/visible on={#1}}}}}



\begin{document}

\frame{

\begin{forest}
[S
  [NP$_x$ [he,tier=words]]
  [VP
    [V x z y
      [V x y, circle edge={/tikz/visible on=<3>}
        [baked]]]
    [NP$_z$ [her,tier=words]]
    [NP$_y$ [a cake,roof,tier=words]]]]
\end{forest}

\pause\pause\pause



}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** My solution below works for simple cases like `<3->`but it fails for `<2,4>`because of the comma. Is there a way to get the comma through to `beamer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deal with the comma in an overlay specification by using curly brackets around it.

```
          [V x y, circle edge=<{2,4}>
```

You can control the colour of the ellipse, without use of a second argument, by declaring a `toks` option.

For example, use `circle edge colour` for the colour and then use this option as the value for `draw` when drawing the node.

```
\forestset{%
  circle edge/.style={
    tikz+={
      \node [fit=(.child anchor) (!u.parent anchor), visible on=#1, ellipse, inner ysep=1.5pt, line
      width=0.25mm, draw=\foresteoption{circle edge colour}] {};
    },
  },
```

Declare the option and set the default for a red ellipse.

```
  declare toks={circle edge colour}{red},
}
```

Putting this together, we can create a blue ellipse on slides 2 and 4.

```
          [V x y, circle edge=<{2,4}>, circle edge colour=blue
```

[image: ellipse on slides 2 and 4 in non-default blue]

Complete code (note that the `\pause\pause\pause` is superfluous as far as I can tell):

```
% addaswyd o ateb (a chwestiwn) Stefan Müller: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355485/
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}
\forestset{%
  circle edge/.style={
    tikz+={
      \node [fit=(.child anchor) (!u.parent anchor), visible on=#1, ellipse, inner ysep=1.5pt, line
      width=0.25mm, draw=\foresteoption{circle edge colour}] {};
    },
  },
  declare toks={circle edge colour}{red},
}

\tikzset{% set up for transitions using tikz with beamer overlays - developed by Daniel (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/) and, in earlier form, by Matthew Leingang (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/) and modified for this use, I think by Qrrbrbirlbel (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112471/)
  invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    [S
      [NP$_x$ [he,tier=words]]
      [VP
        [V x z y
          [V x y, circle edge=<{2,4}>, circle edge colour=blue
            [baked]]]
        [NP$_z$, calign with current [her,tier=words]]
        [NP$_y$ [a cake,roof,tier=words]]]]
  \end{forest}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer here [Using beamer overlays with forest generated trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109950/using-beamer-overlays-with-forest-generated-trees/112471#112471). One can call the `visible on` style in `circle edge` and pass the `<3->` information as an argument. An open issue is how to pass `<2,4>`. The comma is a problem.

The only disadvantage of this is that one cannot pass the color argument for the color of the ellipse without having two arguments.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,fit}

\forestset{%
  circle edge/.style={
    tikz+={
          \node [fit=(.child anchor) (!u.parent anchor), draw=red, visible on=#1, ellipse, inner ysep=1.5pt, line
            width=0.25mm] {};
        }
  },
}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}

\begin{document}

\frame{

\begin{forest}
[S
  [NP$_x$ [he,tier=words]]
  [VP
    [V x z y
      [V x y, circle edge=<3->
        [baked]]]
    [NP$_z$ [her,tier=words]]
    [NP$_y$ [a cake,roof,tier=words]]]]
\end{forest}

\pause\pause\pause



}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't actually need the `\forestset` `visible on` part here - you aren't using it at all.

Comment: I am very sorry. This is really embarrassing. Usually I do this and I also have the URL in the code I use. I removed it from the code here since it does not belong there, but I should have provided it in the description. Did this now.

Comment: Do you know a way to deal with `<2,4>`?

Comment: Please see my answer below. You can declare a `toks` for the colour and just need curly brackets to deal with the comma.

Comment: I tried the curly brackets everywhere but inside the angle brackets. Thanks!